# How to filter an ADO recordset with AND operator

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

I have this VBA code that save and edit many informations in a Microsoft Accsess database.

In one sub, I need to filter my recordset with an AND operator.

I have this now:

```
rst.Filter = "OT ='" & oot & "'"
rst.Filter = "Parcial ='" & PARCIAL & "'"
rst.Delete
```

And I would like to transform it into something like this:

```
rst.Filter = "OT ='" & oot & "'"  AND  "Parcial ='" & PARCIAL & "'"
rst.Delete
```

Here is the entire sub:

```
Sub delete_ot()

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection 'dim the ADO collection class
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset 'dim the ADO recordset class
Dim dbPath
Dim x As Long, i As Long
Dim nextrow As Long
Dim wsc As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim oot As String
Dim PARCIAL As String

PARCIAL = Corte.PARCIAL

oot = CStr(Corte.TextBox16)

On Error GoTo errHandler:


Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsc = wb.Worksheets("Auxiliar")

Dim folderPath As String
folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Dim pasta As String

pasta = folderPath & "\" & wsc.Range("J2").Value
dbPath = pasta & "\" & wsc.Range("J4").Value & ".accdb"

'Initialise the collection class variable
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
'ConnectionString Open '—-5 aguments—-
'Source, ActiveConnection, CursorType, LockType, Options
rst.Open Source:="Registro_corte", ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
Options:=adCmdTable


rst.Filter = "OT ='" & oot & "'"
rst.Filter = "Parcial ='" & PARCIAL & "'"
rst.Delete

'close the recordset
rst.Close
' Close the connection
cnn.Close
'clear memory
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
errHandler:
'Clear memory
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
MsgBox "Error FAVOR AVISAR ENGENHARIA " & err.Number & " (" & err.Description & ") in procedure Delete_OT"

End Sub
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND` becomes part of the filter string:

`rst.Filter = "OT ='" & oot & "' AND Parcial ='" & PARCIAL & "'"`